# How to format all the values in dictionary using python?

Tags: python

how can we format a number in a dictionary in python?
I have {'num1' : 0.111, 'num2' : 0.222}
How to round them up or make them like 0.1 and 0.2 in the printed results?

Comment: What part of the problem are you having trouble with? Rounding a number? Updating a dictionary? Iterating over every element of a dictionary? Printing a formatted float? Please share what you tried - your question is about a quite trivial problem, so you should be able to try at least something yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion since I'm new in this field, and thanks for responding here is more information:
I'm using nltk for natural language processing in my code. Here is the code:     def sentimentAnalyse(text):
        score = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer().polarity_scores(text)
        print(score)
the result is  like this: {'num1' : 0.111, 'num2' : 0.222} and I want to format the values to get only one decimal point not three.

Answer (score 0):

As @j1-lee said in comment, you don't "format a number variable", but instead you format the printed value.

To print the key-value pairs:

```
d = {'num1' : 0.111, 'num2' : 0.222}
for k, v in d.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v:.2f}")
```

**More Explanation**
You **can** update the values in the dict to round the floats, but that would be a terrific idea and you would encounter rounding issues all of the time.

If you insist doing so though,

```
d = {'num1' : 0.111, 'num2' : 0.222}
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = round(v,2)
print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.